# Which APNS certificate do I need for Development Deployment

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

In xcode when you go to archive, one of the methods for export is...

"Save for Development Deployment"

Typically I've done an Ad Hoc deployment which would require a production APNS certificate to connect to apple's production gateway.

However, for this development deployment, would the sandbox APNS work? Or do I need to use proudction apns for this?

Also, does provision profile matter? Can I use this option with my regular developer provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

If you select "Save for Development Deployment", your app will be code signed with your development certificate, so you need to use the development APNS certificate and the sandbox APNS.